# How to fix ChromeDriver that does not open Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

so I found a code online, it shows no errors, but when I start the code, even Chrome isn't opening. After a few seconds code ends running. I dont know how to solve this problem so if some of you can help me, I would be pleased. Note : I have the right version of ChoromeDriver installed.

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from os import link
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random
import string
import re

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = False # как будет запускаться хром - в фоне или нет
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(20)  # количество одновременных потоков


def generate_random_string(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    rand_string = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    return rand_string


# простейшая функция выгрузки всех ссылок с заданой страницы
def getlinks(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(rpath='chromedriver.exe', options=chromeOptions)
    # path к chromedriver
    list = []
    driver.get(url)
    a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
    i = 0
    for b in a:
        i = i + 1
        link = b.get_attribute("href")
        list.insert(i, link)
    driver.quit()
    return list


def scrape(url, scraper=None):
    executor.submit(scraper, url)
    executor.submit(scraper, 'a link' +generate_random_string(10))

    # генерируем мусорные ссылки, если надо. кстати, если в тестируемом сайте
    # есть функция поиска или любые другие страницы с тяжелыми запросами в БД,
    # этот вариант - твой

    def scraper(url):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(rpath='chromedriver.exe', options=chromeOptions)
        # path к chromedriver
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(15)
        driver.quit()

    urls = getlinks('a link')
    for url in urls * 10:  # количество инстансов
        scrape(url)
```

Where 'a link' is written there meant to be the target link. I have Selenium and ChromeDriver installed in the directory of the project.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Think you just have the wrong chrome driver version, make sure your chrome driver is equal to the version your google currently is

[Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

[How to get google version](https://www.businessinsider.com/what-version-of-google-chrome-do-i-have?op=1&r=US&IR=T)

Comment: that didnt work :(